# Why isn't the file being validated in Laravel on Android?

Tags: android, laravel-5

Laravel 5.1, 
Android any

There is a Controller with Request'om in which it is checked that the field is a file.
On PC, ios everything works fine. But when you send a request from any Android device, the validation on the file does not pass. What could be the problem?

Headers **Android**:

```
:authority: *hide*
:method: POST
:path: /api/storage-files/upload
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
authorization: Bearer *hide*
content-length: 3454764
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYr0MZZ0rMJLl5sm9
cookie: __stripe_mid=cfc323d6-af83-430e-9f6f-d33e8cc1ffc3; __stripe_sid=35e6d7a1-f2bf-4d0b-b199-d852d127a476; messagesUtk=8ee0c450327645a2a3c82b7186f825a0; __remjt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI5MDUyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi53b290ZXIuY28vYXBpL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTU4Mjg4NDAwNSwiZXhwIjo1OTk0MDYwMTU4Mjg4Mzk0NSwibmJmIjoxNTgyODg0MDA1LCJqdGkiOiIxdDBQcTRIZ1k4VlBBUWZRIn0.3fy4aQ-6_ZlQ24iRK_gYsJNRI6kavl6YliIraen33Eg;
origin: *hide*
referer: *hide*
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Redmi Note 5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.119 Mobile Safari/537.3
```

Headers **PC**:

```
:authority: *hide*
:method: POST
:path: /api/storage-files/upload
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
authorization: Bearer *hide*
content-length: 23479
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryXgKf5soaXwGBBSlH
cookie: __insp_wid=1445796083; __insp_slim=1582884323068; __insp_nv=true; __insp_targlpu=aHR0cHM6Ly9vcmRlci53b290ZXIuY28v; __insp_targlpt=V29vdGVyIEFwcGFyZWw%3D; messagesUtk=5a1d38d712584ff0b2a51e293a16d324; __insp_pad=1; __insp_sid=2050589431; __insp_uid=1850924571; __stripe_mid=bea6de0b-e04e-48bf-8350-e1a5f3036b5b; __stripe_sid=945fea97-8153-493e-a013-61c6cabd7bf6; __hstc=219564742.ff885e014dec86c4b6961bfa88dbef06.1582884329546.1582884329546.1582884329546.1; hubspotutk=ff885e014dec86c4b6961bfa88dbef06; __hssrc=1; __remjt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI5MDUyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi53b290ZXIuY28vYXBpL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTU4Mjg4NDMzOCwiZXhwIjo1OTk0MDYwMTU4Mjg4NDI3OCwibmJmIjoxNTgyODg0MzM4LCJqdGkiOiI2cXRhc0dWdjZwa29DekxsIn0.Xsby0U0jndyJQuQUHtSd8i3_16tO2bN0MWGFMa3Idxo; __hssc=219564742.4.1582884329547; hs-messages-hide-welcome-message=true
origin:  *hide*
referer:  *hide*
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/70.0.3538.67 Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947383/uploading-file-from-android-to-laravel-via-api
Have you checked it's answer?

Comment: In my example, validation doesn't go any further.

Comment: Please provide the upload code and the form to receive it, so we can replicate and help to sort it out.